# How to boot from CD rom in a Sunfire v250 server

Tags: linux, debian, installation, boot

I have a **Sunfire v250** server that currenlty has **Debian** installed, I need to make a fresh Debian install with the newest stable version, but I cannot make it boot from the Debian CD.

The servers boots into SILO and I try to do:

```
boot cdrom -s
```

without any results, Do you have any idea on how to boot from CD?

Comment: Are you sure you have a CD and not a DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the cd/dvd is bootable?  Can you boot another server (or even your laptop) from that cd? Most common issue is the cd itself, not server.